# Modify options menu while it is visible before API 11

Tags: android

My options menu contains a "refresh" button that triggers an `AsyncTask`. I would like to have that button disabled while the task is running.

Can I modify an options menu even *while it is visible*, and if so, how?

Or can I at least force it to refresh and call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` again?

*Note:* I am on API level 8, so I cannot call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in deprecated paradigm of android menus.

But you can migrate to new "actionBar" paradigm. While native [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) class is available only from API level 11, you still can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library, which is backported to API level 4